# Pattern match and conditionally bind in a single Switch statement

Tags: swift, swift2, switch-statement, swift3, conditional-binding

Is there a way to write this `if`/`else if`/`else` ladder as a switch statement?

```
let x: Any = "123"

if let s = x as? String {
    useString(s)
}
else if let i = x as? Int {
    useInt(i)
}
else if let b = x as? Bool {
    useBool(b)
}
else {
    fatalError()
}
```

Here's my attempt:

```
switch x {
case let s where s is String:   useString(s)
case let i where i is Int:      useInt(i)
case let b where b is Bool:     useBool(b)
default: fatalError()
}
```

It successfully chooses the right path, but `s`/`i`/`b` are still of type `Any`. The `is` check doesn't have any effect in casting them. This forces me to force cast with `as!` before usage.

Is there a way to switch on the type, and bind it to a name, all in one `switch` statement?

Comment: What you are doing is correct but missing executable statements for each `case`. Just add a `print` and see you wont see any errors

Comment: Yes, that's an error, but I omitted it for the sake of demonstration. `print(_:)` has no problem handling parameters of type `Any`. Imagine the comments like `//use s` are actually function calls that take a parameter of type `String`/`Int`/`Bool`, respectively.

Comment: You said - "but s/i/b are still of type Any. The `is` check doesn't have any effect in casting them" So if you really print `s/i/b` then actually it prints the right value. `print(s)`. I didn't knw about your function `useString`. Thanks

Comment: Actually it is demonstrated as an example in the Swift Book: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338, search for `for thing in things` ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, you can use the [conditional casting pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID425) `case let x as Type`:

```
let x: Any = "123"

switch x {
case let s as String:
    print(s)   //use s
case let i as Int:
    print(i)   //use i
case let b as Bool:
    print(b)   //use b
default:
    fatalError()
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'll accept in 5 minutes

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Happy to help :)