# How can you case-match on a function/closure stored in a variable?

Tags: swift, pattern-matching

Consider this code:

```
func testA(){}
func testB(value:Int){}
func testC(value:String){}

var someTest:Any = testA
```

How do you case-match on a variable holding a closure to find the correct one so you can call it?

```
switch someTest{
    case let test where test:() -> Void:
        test()
    case let test where test:(value:Int) -> Void:
        test(4)
    case let test where test:(value:String) -> Void:
        test("A")
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: You want e.g `case let test as (String) -> Void`, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/38980403/2976878

Comment: Though depending on your use case, you may want to consider using an `enum` with associated values for each function type; then you can exhaustively switch without having to type-cast.

Comment: @Alexander: That Q&A does not cover matching against closures, I wonder if this is worth a separate answer (preferably from Hamish due to his initial comment)

Comment: Duh! as not where. Of course! Hamish, post that as an answer and I’ll accept it.

Comment: @MarqueR IDK. Closures are such well-integrated types in the type system that I didn't (personally) expect them to be an exception in this case. Perhaps others would find it surprising

Comment: @Alexander, I think you messed up our names. It was 'MartinR', not 'MarqueR'.  Also, I agree with him in that this should probably not be marked as a duplicate.  While closures are types as you correctly pointed out, they sometimes tend to still be thought of differently even though they aren't.  For instance, I just made that very mistake that seems obvious in hindsight.

Comment: Haha yes I did, and fair enough, i'll reopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure types are subject to the same switching patterns that any other types are:

```
switch someClosure {
    case let runnable as () -> Void:
        runnable()
    case let intConsumer as (Int) -> Void:
        intConsumer(4)
    case let stringConsumer as (String) -> Void:
        stringConsumer("A")
}
```