# Is it possible to use Any? in our Model class when we are not sure what the data type our Model will receive

Tags: json, swift, model

I am having an error in mapping my json data to the model, so I decided to keep the variables of model class to Any?. But I am not sure whether it's programmatically correct to keep all or some of your model values to Any data type.

Comment: Using Any is not a good solution, it's better to solve the underlying problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll likely have to do is when converting from JSON to Foundation types, have the type's values be of `Any` type. For example:

```swift
guard let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:Any] else {
    return
}
```

You'll then have to test the type of the value received and handle each situation appropriately:

```swift
guard let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:Any] else {
    return
}

switch jsonObject["key"] {
case let int as Int:

    //Handle Int scenario

case let string as String:

    //Handle String scenario

case let bool as Bool:

    //Handle Bool scenario

case let array as Array:

    //Handle array scenario

case nil:

    //Handle null scenario

default:

    //Other type?

}
```

You could then have a property of type `Any` in your model that will be cast to a certain type at a later point. Similarly, you could have multiple optional properties for each type. For example, your model could have the following properties:

```swift
class MyModel {
    var int: Int?
    var string: String?
    var bool: Bool?
    var array: Array?
}
```

And then, for each instance of this model, only one of these four optional properties will ever actually be set. Then later on you would, of course, check and handle for each scenario.

Comment: If only one of the fields of `MyModel` would ever be set, then a `class` would be an inappropriate choice. An `enum` is a perfect fit. And btw, you can write out type-casting `if let`/`else if let`/`else` ladders as `switch` statements (`case let i as Int: ...`). Looks much tidier

Comment: Interesting, I've never encountered type-casting in a switch statement (I'm still a student), thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Note: in your edited answer, your switch case is only checking types, and never actually casting. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980478/3141234

Comment: Good call @Alexander